# How to calc CheckSum8 Modulo 256

Tags: javascript

i need to calc checksum like this site
https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

for hex 313233343536373839 the site calc DD

with my function i get 168, how exactly to do it?

```
function calculateChecksum8Modulo256(data) {
  let checksum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    checksum = (checksum + data.charCodeAt(i)) % 256;
  }
  return checksum;
}

let res = calculateChecksum8Modulo256('313233343536373839')
```

Comment: `charCodeAt` gives you the UTF-16 code of the character, which is equivalent to ASCII in this case. So you should input the characters "123456789" instead of its ASCII in hex, because you are going to convert the character to ASCII by `charCodeAt`

Comment: `49 + 50 + 51 + 52 + 53 + 54 + 55 + 56 + 57 = 477` => `477 % 256 = 221` => `221` convert to `hex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the same result, you need to consider every two characters in the string as a byte represented as hexadecimal. At the end, use `.toString(16)` to get the hexadecimal representation of the sum.

```js
function calculateChecksum8Modulo256(data) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length;)
    res = (res + parseInt(data.slice(i, i += 2), 16)) & 0xFF;
  return res.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}

console.log(calculateChecksum8Modulo256('313233343536373839'));
```

Comment: Why not let the for loop do the incrementing?

Comment: @gre_gor Mainly to avoid duplicating `i + 2` (the offset only has to be written once like this).